# How to use the %T>% pipe after ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pipeline

Let's take a look at the following two pieces of code:

```
mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
    geom_line()
```

This works and creates the following plot:

[image]

Now let's look at this:

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
```

This also works and creates the following output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl   mpg
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  26.7
2     6  19.7
3     8  15.1
```

However, this doesn't work:

```
mtcars %T>%
    ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
    geom_line() %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
```

It gives the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("group_by") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "c('LayerInstance', 'Layer', 'ggproto', 'gg')"
```

Why doesn't it work? From the `%T>%` documentation, I would expect that the left-hand side object, in this case, `mtcars`, would be returned after `ggplot`. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. Did I misunderstand the `%T>%` pipe? How is the code supposed to look like to make this work?

Comment: You haven't misunderstood the `%T>%` operator. You have misunderstood the `+.gg` operator (i.e. when adding the `geom_line` call to your plot). The ggplot code needs to be grouped together as a single unit (e.g. by wrapping it in curly brackets). The way you have written your code, there is a new pipeline starting with the `geom_line` call, which you are then passing to `group_by`. Conceptually, the magrittr operators are evaluated before the `+` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `ggplot` call in a `print` so you get both calls. You can use the following code:

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.2
library(magrittr)
#> Warning: package 'magrittr' was built under R version 4.1.2
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'magrittr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     set_names
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     extract
mtcars %T>%
  {print(ggplot(., aes(x = cyl, y = mpg))+
  geom_line())} %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise(mpg = mean(mpg))
```

[image]

```
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>     cyl   mpg
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  26.7
#> 2     6  19.7
#> 3     8  15.1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>